# Where should I put close() method?

Tags: java, exception, file-io

In the following code, where should the close locate? Should it be in the try clause or in finally? If it is finally, should it be enclosed with another try-catch? Thanks.

```
PrintWriter out = null;
try {
    out = new PrintWriter(
            new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter("out.txt", true)));
    out.println("the text");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
} finally {
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The finally block will get executed no matter what. So i think its correct to put it in there.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: If 1.7 or above, use [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle `close` properly, one should ensure that it gets called whether or not an exception occurs in the main-line code, but one should also ensure that if `close` gets called following an exception in the main-line and then throws an exception itself, it won't cause the main-line exception to be discarded; depending upon various factors including whether the object was open for reading or writing, it may be desirable to either let the main-line exception percolate up (perhaps encapsulating information about the close failure), log or encapsulate the main-line exception but have the `close` failure percolate up, or throw a "double fault" exception which encapsulates both of the others.

The try-with-resources feature of Java 7 provides pretty good behavior for many scenarios: if an exception occurs in `try` and another in `close`, the latter exceptions get added to a list of suppressed exceptions (which exception-handling code should look for).  If a method is supposed to grab data from a wireless sensor and write it to a file, and if the caller will expect that in the event of sensor trouble the file will hold as much information as was read successfully, then a failure to close the file may be more important than a sensor failure [if the sensor e.g. only includes "return oldest item" and "delete oldest item" commands, then *if the file closed properly* an exception during sensor communication would mean that any data which was no longer in the sensor would be in the file.  If the file didn't close properly, that would imply that there might have been permanent data loss, and someone should be told about it.

Code to handle the "sensor capture" scenario would end up being a bit icky: the sensor read logic would be placed within a `try` block whose `finally` would capture any exception to a variable.  The `finally` block would then have to use its own `try` block for the close; if an exception occurs there, throw a custom `writeFileCloseFailure` exception which encapsulates both the exception (if any) from the `try` block and the exception from the `close`; otherwise, rethrow the exception (if any) from the `try` block.  Note that since `ioException` could represent either a failure to get data from the sensor (somewhat expected and tolerable) or a failure to write the file (very bad), wrapping in another exception type would allow the caller to distinguish those conditions.

Answer (score 4):

See the documentation for [`try`-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). If you're using at least Java 7, there's a nice syntax for this. Otherwise, the `finally` block is appropriate, since it should be closed in both the normal and exceptional cases.

Answer (score 3):

Put it in the finally block.

Because you should close the `Writer` in either case (exception or no exception).